# Expressão regular para arquivo zip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails4, imagemagick

Como adicionar um arquivo zip em vez de uma imagem?

```
    class UploadDatabase < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_attached_file :zip_file, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
        validates_attachment_content_type :zip_file, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
    end
```

Comment: Qual a gem que você está usando para isso?

Answer (score 1):

Tem 2 erros no seu código:

1. O modelo está configurado para pós-processar o arquivo usando o imagemagick para gerar previews. Isso não é possível para arquivos zip
2. Os arquivos zip serão recusados no final do upload porque o modelo está configurado para aceitar imagens.

Para corrigir:

1. Modificar a linha com **has_attached_file :zip_file...** removendo as configurações de pós-processamento de imagens
2. Modificar o content-type para permitir arquivos com mime type para zip

O código seria:

```
class UploadDatabase < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :zip_file
  validates_attachment_content_type :zip_file,
                                    content_type: [
                                        "application/zip",
                                        "application/x-zip",
                                        "application/x-zip-compressed"
                                    ]
end
```